# Частица не или ни?

Tags: не-или-ни

Моя жизнь уже не дискотека.......

Comment: Это частица, а не приставка.

Answer (score 3):

НЕ — отрицательная частица. Она придает отрицательное значение тому члену предложения, перед которым стоит:
не в первый [во второй, в третий] раз; не тот [другой] город.
[Частицы НЕ и НИ](https://therules.ru/vowels-13/)

**Моя жизнь уже не дискотека...**

*У меня жизнь **не сахар**, хоть я и зарабатываю...* (Д. Пьясор. Лекарство от рутины)

*Нет, жизнь моя совсем **не сказка**.

И даже в праздник — проза дня.*
И. Кунцевич

Answer (score 2):

Отрицательная частица НЕ (нет усилительного значения): **Моя жизнь уже не дискотека..**